# Pandas - image to DataFrame

Tags: python, image, pandas

I want to convert an RGB image into a DataFrame, so that I have the co-ordinates of each pixel and their RGB value.

```
         x   y   red  green  blue
0        0   0   154      0     0
1        1   0   149    111     0
2        2   0   153      0     5
3        0   1   154      0     9
4        1   1   154     10    10
5        2   1   154      0     0
```

I can extract the RGB into a DataFrame quite easily

```
colourImg = Image.open("test.png")
colourPixels = colourImg.convert("RGB")
colourArray = np.array(colourPixels.getdata())

df = pd.DataFrame(colourArray, columns=["red","green","blue"])
```

But I don't know how to get the X & Y coordinates in there.  I *could* write a loop, but on a large image that takes a long time.

Comment: A 3 channel image has 3 dimensions... how do you explain only two coordinates?

Comment: Each pixel has an X and Y position. Each pixel also has a R, G, B value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `np.indices` unfortunately it ends up with a array where the coordinate is the first dimension, but you can do a bit of `np.moveaxis` to fix that.

```
colourImg = Image.open("test.png")
colourPixels = colourImg.convert("RGB")
colourArray = np.array(colourPixels.getdata()).reshape(colourImg.size + (3,))
indicesArray = np.moveaxis(np.indices(colourImg.size), 0, 2)
allArray = np.dstack((indicesArray, colourArray)).reshape((-1, 5))


df = pd.DataFrame(allArray, columns=["y", "x", "red","green","blue"])
```

It's not the pretiest, but it seems to work (edit: fixed x,y being the wrong way around).

Comment: Worked perfectly - and much faster than my attempts - many thanks!

Comment: How Can I apply reverse process of this?  I have X, Y coordnates and R,G, B values in dataframe which looks like X, Y, R, G, B. How can convert dataframe to image by preserving the coordinates.

Comment: It has an error actually, since PIL coordinates are (col, row) and for arrays it is (row, col), you need to reverse colourImg.size: 

colourArray = np.array(colourPixels.getdata()).reshape(tuple(reversed(colourImg.size)) + (3,))   
indicesArray = np.moveaxis(np.indices(reversed(colourImg.size)), 0, 2)

Comment: Otherwise, it will mess up rows and columns. For instance, if you have 384 rows and 512 columns, df.iloc[511] must be the pixel in the right up corner of the image, y=0 and x=511, but it will be y=1 and x=129 (511-383) instead.

Answer (score 3):

I've named the coordinates 'col' and 'row' to be explicit and avoid confusion if the x-coordinate is reffering to the column number or row number of your original pixel array:

```
A = colourArray

# Create the multiindex we'll need for the series
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    (*map(range, A.shape[:2]), ('r', 'g', 'b')),
    names=('row', 'col', None)
)

# Can be chained but separated for use in explanation
df = pd.Series(A.flatten(), index=index)
df = df.unstack()
df = df.reset_index().reindex(columns=['col', 'row', 'r', 'g', 'b'])
```

---

**Explanation:**

`pd.Series(A.flatten(), index=index)` will create a multiindex series where each channel intensity is accessible via `df[row_n, col_n][channel_r_g_or_b]`. The `df` variable (currently a series) will now look something like this:

```
row  col   
0    0    r    116
          g     22
          b    220
     1    r     75
          g    134
          b     43
              ... 
255  246  r     79
          g      9
          b    218
     247  r    225
          g    172
          b    172
```

`unstack()` will pivot the third index (channel index), returning a dataframe with columns `b`, `g`, `r` with each row indexed by a multiindex of `(row_n, col_n)`. The `df` now looks like this:

```
           b    g    r
row col               
0   0    220   22  116
    1     43  134   75
    2    187   97   33
... ...  ...  ...  ...
255 226  156  242  128
    227  221   63  212
    228   75  110  193
```

We then call `reset_index()` to get rid of the `(row_n, col_n)` multiindex and just have a flat `0..⁠(n_pixels-1)` index. The `df` is now:

```
       row  col    b    g    r
0        0    0  220   22  116
1        0    1   43  134   75
2        0    2  187   97   33
...    ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
65506  255  226  156  242  128
65507  255  227  221   63  212
65508  255  228   75  110  193
```

And then a simple `reindex()` to rearrange the columns into `col`, `row`, `r`, `g`, `b` order.

---

**Timings:**

Now as for how fast this runs, well... for a 3-channel image, here are the timings:

```
Size       Time
  250x250  58.2 ms
  500x500   251 ms
1000x1000  1.03 s
2500x2500  8.14 s
```

Admittedly not great on images > 1 MP. `unstack()` can take a while after the df gets very large.

I've tried [@davidsheldon's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49650363/8944057) and it ran a lot quicker, for a 2500x2500 image, it took 244 ms, and a 10000x10000 image took 9.04 s.

Comment: I think `x` and `y` is more clear compared to `row` and `col`, when talking about pictures... +1 though ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I created a little package using the davidsheldon's answer. Thank you!
You can use

`pip install pd2img`

to install it. It is also possible to reverse the process (save the dataframe as an image). By the way: If the image has an alpha channel, the dataframe will have an additional column for that!

Here is everything you need to know:

```
from pd2img import Pd2Img
df = Pd2Img(r"C:\Users\Gamer\Documents\Downloads\WhatsApp 
Image 2022-04-21 at 5.07.14 PM.jpeg")  # creating an instance
df.to_file_rgb('f:\\testimagefile1.png')  # save the 
dataframe to an RGB image
df.to_file_rgba('f:\\testimagefile2.png')  # save the dataframe to an RGBA image 
np3 = df.to_numpy_rgb()  # convert the image to an numpy array (RGB, not BGR!)
np4 = df.to_numpy_rgba()  # convert the image to an numpy array (RGBA)
print(df.df)  # printing the dataframe
           y     x  red  green  blue
0          0     0  155    150   144
1          0     1  155    150   144
```