# Greater performance in large list operations in python

Tags: python, image, list, performance

I'm developing a small software for a college project and I'm having a problem: The code has a way too low performance.

It's an image editing software, and the image is a larg 3d list (the main list is the whole image, each list inside it is an horizontal line and each list inside that one is a pixel, containing three elements).

I need to make pixel-by-pixel adjustments, like multiplying all of them by a constant, so it would go like

```
for y in range(0,len(image)): 
    for x in range (0,len(image[0])):
        for c in range (0,3):
            im[y][x][c] = (im[y][x][c])*a
```

Where `image` is the 3d list
`len(image)` is the amount of horizontal lines in the image (vertical size)
`len(image[0])` is the amount of pixels in a horizontal line (horizontal size)
and `c` is the component of the pixel (going from 0 to 2).

This loop takes several minutes to go through a single 12 MP image and the amount of images I have to process is in the order of the hundreds, so this is just impossible.

What can I do to get a greater performance? Even editing softwares take some seconds because it can be a pretty large operation, but this code is just too slow.

Thank you!

Comment: This question most likely belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why not use specilaized libraries like `OpenCV` or `PIL`? If it is prohibited, consider using `NumPy` arrays - they are significantly faster than lists

Comment: The problem here is that you need to iterate over each pixel. And this is a classical example of where you most likely want to use a library specifically designed for this kind of task. [python-pillow (PIL)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/) is a good start, others are [python-numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) for data structures or [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649215/pandas-image-to-dataframe).

Comment: Well, my pixel manipulation functions are custom, I don't know if i'm going to find them anywhere else, but, there is in fact one case that is simple which is this one I used in this post, just multiplying by a constant. But I didn't create the list, it's the tifffile module that does that in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I also (as in the comments) suggest using Numpy.
Sample code would be something like this:

```py
import numpy as np

im = np.array(image,dtype="float16")

# Define your custom function
def myFunc(x,a):
    x = x * a
    return x

# Vectorise function
vfunc = np.vectorize(myFunc)

# Apply function to the array with the parameter a = 5
im = vfunc(im,5)
```

I compared timings for a vectorized numpy function and nested loops for an array of the size roughly eqivalent to a 12MP image: 4242 x 2828 x 3.

Nested loops took *99* second, while numpy took about *6.5* secs.

For your reference here is a question about numpy functions efficiency: [Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)

For simple functions like multiplication using numpy native functions is the fastest.

```
# Multiply each element by 5
im = im * 5
```

This code took only 0.5 sec on my machine.