# How can I use 'fromarray' on an array of an image from dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-imaging-library

I opened two pictures from files (they are the same size) and created arrays from them. I added these two arrays to a new dataframe, and now I want to create images from these two elements of the dataframe. As I'm using 'fromarray', like normally for images which formed with 'asarray', it does not work. What code shall I use instead of? Thank you in advance for your help.

```
from numpy import asarray
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd

image1 = Image.open("imageA")
image2 = Image.open("imageB")

data1 = asarray(image1)
data2 = asarray(image2)

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['1stPic'] = data1.tolist()
df['2ndPic'] = data2.tolist()

imageNew = Image.fromarray(df[0])
```

then I should get the picture again like in case when I use 'asarray' and 'fromarray'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image.fromarray` waits 8-bit integers. Multiply by 255 and convert to uint8 to get the output.

**[Edit-1]**
This problem also has 2 solutions:

1- (Long way) Add to DataFrame with PIL ( [More Detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649215/pandas-image-to-dataframe) )

```
colourImg = Image.open("test.png")
colourPixels = colourImg.convert("RGB")
colourArray = np.array(colourPixels.getdata()).reshape(colourImg.size + (3,))
indicesArray = np.moveaxis(np.indices(colourImg.size), 0, 2)
allArray = np.dstack((indicesArray, colourArray)).reshape((-1, 5))


df = pd.DataFrame(allArray, columns=["y", "x", "red","green","blue"])

#DataFrame to image 
colourArray = np.array(colourPixels.getdata()).reshape(tuple(reversed(colourImg.size)) + (3,)) 
indicesArray = np.moveaxis(np.indices(reversed(colourImg.size)), 0, 2)
```

2- Use `py2img` 
example :

```
from pd2img import Pd2Img
df = Pd2Img(r"C:\path\to\image.jpeg")  # creating an instance
df.to_file_rgb('f:\\testimagefile1.png')  # save the dataframe to an RGB image
df.to_file_rgba('f:\\testimagefile2.png')  # save the dataframe to an RGBA image 
np3 = df.to_numpy_rgb()  # convert the image to an numpy array (RGB)
np4 = df.to_numpy_rgba()  # convert the image to an numpy array (RGBA)
```

**[EDIT-2]**
The problem with the above code is that `py2img` is returning the DataFrame with red blue green values ​​in different places and the image is different from the original image. If we fix the code like this, there will be no problem. If we show it in my picture:

Input :

> [image: final image]

```
from pd2img import Pd2Img
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = Pd2Img(r"114087659.png")
print(df.df)
>>>          y    x  red  green  blue
>>> 0        0    0   89     66    35
>>> 1        0    1   90     60    33
>>> 2        0    2   90     62    37
>>> 3        0    3   87     66    40
>>> 4        0    4   84     66    40
>>> ...    ...  ...  ...    ...   ...
>>> 77836  278  274    0      0     0
>>> 77837  278  275    0      0     0
>>> 77838  278  276    0      0     0
>>> 77839  278  277    0      0     0
>>> 77840  278  278    0      0     0

# Get image to Dataframe:
maxlen = df.df.x.max()
red = np.array(np.array_split(df.df.red.to_numpy(), maxlen + 1))
green = np.array(np.array_split(df.df.green.to_numpy(), maxlen+ 1))
blue = np.array(np.array_split(df.df.blue.to_numpy(), maxlen + 1))
myImage = np.dstack((red, green, blue))

plt.imshow(myImage)
plt.show()
```

Output :

> [image: final image]

Comment: How do I need to correct this trying on my solution?
df['1stPic'] = data1.tolist()
df['2ndPic'] = data2.tolist()
df = (df*255).astype(np.uint8)

imageNew = Image.fromarray(df[0])
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, I hope this 2 way help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I tryied the second option, because I find it easier to use for creating a dataframe with e.g. images, while I can call any of them (correct me if it's still easy with the 1st code as well). For the 2nd code I opened the image with Image.fromarray(np3, "RGB").show(), but the picture was nonsense, so I added .astype("uint8") to the line of np3. Now the image is correct, but the colors are a bit mismatched. What shall I do to correct the colors? Multiplying by 255 makes it too brightful.

Comment: Edited! Did it solve your problem @SzeJan?

Comment: Hey @heywtu ! My aim was to convert these arrays to images and open them with PIL Image, so I had to use '.astype('uint8)' yet, but then it worked perfectly! Many thanks for your help and patience! One remaining question dat I'm wondering, if I want to create a dataframe with e.g. 2 images, with this code I shall just create another df for the 2nd image, and add it to the 1st df with 'append()' to always choose the 3 columns for the image which are needed, or do you have any better idea?

Comment: (I assume that you have done the above operations for both images) If you want to overwrite existing data. Let's say the name of the 3rd column is red. df1['red'] = df1['red']+df2['red']
You can add like this. You can do df1.df['red'] = df2.df['red'] if you want to change it.

Comment: Also you need the resize images as same as first image. And this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pillow/Python_pillow_merging_images.htm) can be useful. if you run into problems feel free to bother me